# how to test $window.open using jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

This is my function

```
 $scope.buildForm = function (majorObjectId, name) {
      $window.open("/FormBuilder/Index#/" + $scope.currentAppId + "/form/" + majorObjectId + "/" + name);
  };
```

This is my jasmine test spec

```
            it('should open new window for buildForm and with expected id', function () {
            scope.majorObjectId = mockObjectId;
            scope.currentAppId = mockApplicationId;
            var name = "DepartmentMajor";
            scope.buildForm(mockObjectId, name);
            scope.$digest();
            expect(window.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
            spyOn(window, 'open');
            spyOn(window, 'open').and.returnValue("/FormBuilder/Index#/" + scope.currentAppId + "/form/" + scope.majorObjectId + "/" + name);
        });
```

but when i try to run this it is opening a new tab and i don't want this to happen, i just want to check whether the given returnValues are present are not!!

Comment: It should be `$window` i believe in your tests, Inject `$window`

Comment: i injected $window but even it is opening a new tab after runing

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First of all your expectation (window.open).toHaveBeenCalled() is in wrong place.
You cannot expect before spying the event.
Now coming to your question
there are different methods in jasmine to spy on dependencies,like

- **.and.callThrough** - By chaining the spy with and.callThrough, the spy will still track all calls to it but in addition it will delegate to the actual implementation.
- **.and.callFake** - By chaining the spy with and.callFake, all calls to the spy will delegate to the supplied function.
- **.and.returnValue** - By chaining the spy with and.returnValue, all calls to the function will return a specific value.

> Please check [Jamine doc](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html) for complete list

Sample test case for below as per your requirement

```
$scope.buildForm = function() {
        $window.open( "http://www.google.com" );
    };
```

Will be

```
it( 'should test window open event', inject( function( $window ) {
        spyOn( $window, 'open' ).and.callFake( function() {
            return true;
        } );
        scope.buildForm();
        expect( $window.open ).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect( $window.open ).toHaveBeenCalledWith( "http://www.google.com" );
    } ) );
```