# Errors thrown when unit testing directive with Angular

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a custom directive that uses a service. When I run my unit tests, I keep getting the thrown error 'Library does not exist on window'. How can I avoid getting that error in my Unit test?

**example service**

```
angular.module('example')
  .factory('thirdParty', ['$window', function($window) {

    if (typeof $window.thirdParty === 'undefined') {
      throw new Error('Library does not exist on window');
    } else {
      return $window.thirdParty;
    }

  }]);
```

**custom directive**

```
 angular.module('example')
  .directive('customDirective', ['thirdParty',
    function(thirdParty) {
      var defaults, link;

      link = function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
        // do something with thirdParty
      };

      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: link,
      };
    }]);
```

**test**

```
describe('customDirective', function() {
  var element, compile, scope;

  beforeEach(module('example'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
    compile = $compile;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
  }));

    // Manually compile and link our directive
  function getCompiledElement(template) {
    var compiledElement;

    var validTemplate = '<input ng-model="example.data" custom-directive />';

    compiledElement = compile(template || validTemplate)(scope);
    scope.$digest();

    return compiledElement;
  }

  it('should do something', function() {
    element = getCompiledElement();
    // expects
  });

});
```

Comment: you need to mock your third party factory and restrict call to third party during directive testing. Please Refer to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31286162/how-to-test-window-open-using-jasmine/31302345#31302345) for more info.

Comment: also code would be more test friendly if you wrap you thirdparty factory conditions within a function and do your stuff by calling that function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inject `$window` (stub that out too, for good measure) and stub/mock out the `thirdParty` lib.

```
var $window;

beforeEach(function () {
  $window = {};

  module('yourmodule', function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('$window', $window);
  });

  $window.thirdParty = {};
});
```

---

```
it('throws', function () {
  delete $window.thirdParty;

  function fn () {
    getCompiledElement();
  }  

  expect(fn).to.throw(/does not exist on window/i);
});

it('just works™', function () {
  function fn () {
    getCompiledElement();
  }

  expect(fn).to.not.throw;
});
```